# Graph Theory - Hamiltonian Cycle, Eulerian Trail and Eulerian circuit

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

Is it possible to draw a graph that has an Eulerian trail as well as a Hamiltonian Cycle but does not have an Eulerian circuit?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest example is a square with one diagonal.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I'm new to graph theory so this may be a stupid question... but I'm of the understanding that a Hamiltonian cycle can only visit each vertex once and an Eulerian trail has to visit every edge once. Is this possible with the graph you described? 

Or have I misunderstood the definitions of the two?

Comment: @RJH2191 Hamiltonian cycle: go around the square. Eulerian trail: go along the diagonal, then around the square. No Eulerian cycle because the two corners with the diagonal have odd degrees.